# join two tables in mysql and get records

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have two tables "**contacts**" and "**users**".  Users table storing data with "," separated. Need to distinct data in "**Contacts**" column from "**Contacts**" table. And need to join with "**Users**" table, and get the records.

```
Contacts Table
--------------------------
id |    user_Id      | contats
--------------------------
1  |   2147483647    | 90123456789,90123456789,90123456789,90123456789
2  |   2147483647    | 90123456789,90123456789,90123456789,90123456789
3  |   919444894154  | 90123456789,90123456789,90123456789,90123456789

Users Table
-----------------------------
id | username | email                  | phone
-----------------------------
1  | bhavan   | bhavanram93@gmail.com  | 90123456789
2  | bhavan   | bhavanram93@gmail.com  | 90123456789
3  | prince   | prince@gmail.com       | 1234567980
4  | bhavan   | bhavanram93@gmail.com  | 90123456789
5  | hello    | hello@gmail.com        | 1234567890
6  | bhavan   | bhavanram93@gmail.com  | 90123456789
```

Comment: Check this explained well here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1):

Your table `Contacts` shouldn't be constructed this way.

Since you want 1 `Users` table containing all the data about a user, and 1 `Contacts` table containing links between different users, you'd rather do this kind of table structure :

**Contacts** table

```
id | user_id | contact_id
-------------------------
1  | 1       | 2
2  | 1       | 3
3  | 2       | 3
```

That'll allow you to do something like :

```
SELECT *
FROM Users
JOIN Contacts ON (Users.id = Contacts.contact_id)
WHERE Contacts.user_id = 1
```

Which will return all the data of the contacts of the user 1.

Your current structure is a huge ongoing mess, it's the opposite of being flexible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, We need to remove " ' " (comma) from "contacts" column from "contacts" table right?  That i want to.

Comment: Yes absolutely. For example in your example in your ```contacts``` column there is ```"919444894154,91944654546"```, when you should have 2 lines instead following the same pattern than in my example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows provides an example of how to take a comma separated list and make rows out of it.

Answer (score 1):

You should restructure your db to a normalized format as Steve suggest.

But if you cant:

```
SELECT *
FROM Users
JOIN Contacts 
  ON CONCAT(',', Contacts.contacts, ',') like
     CONCAT('%,', Users.phone, ',%')
WHERE Contacts.user_id = 1
```

the idea is you convert your contacts to

```
,    <numbers>    ,
,90123456789,90123456789,90123456789,90123456789,
```

and try to match with

```
 %,90123456789,%
```

Note this approach cant use any index so will have bad performance with many 
rows. if you are in the order of 1k-10k rows may be ok. More than that you need consider restructure your db.